# ocpsoft rewrite ConfigurationProvider Registration fails

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, url-rewriting, richfaces, ocpsoft-rewrite

I want to use ocpsoft rewrite in order to overcome proxy issues with Richfaces. Since the JavaScript files could not be found through a proxy configuration (similar to the problem described in [JSF. URL rewriting solution needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905946/jsf-url-rewriting-solution-needed)). Somehow I do not manage to register the  `ConfigurationProvider` correctly. Here is the warning message I receive:

> WARNING: No ConfigurationProviders were registered: Rewrite will not
>   be enabled on this application. Did you forget to create a
>   '/META-INF/services/org.ocpsoft.rewrite.config.ConfigurationProvider
>   file containing the fully qualified name of your provider
>   implementation?

The Project layout is as follows:

- `src`

  - `main`

    - `java`
    - `resources`
    - `webapp`

      - `META-INF`

        - `services`

          - `org.ocpsoft.rewrite.config.ConfigurationProvider` (containing the full qualified name to the ConfigurationProvider implementation)
      - `WEB-INF`
      - `resources`
- `target`

My project is Maven based using JSF2 with Richfaces 4.3.0.Final and opcsoft rewrite 1.1.0.Final. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The location of your SPI file is incorrect. It should be:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.ocpsoft.rewrite.config.ConfigurationProvider
```