# jsf resources inproperly resolved via ajp connector

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, primefaces, ajp, mod-proxy-ajp

I have application in JSF2 (using Primefaces). I resolve url to resources using `h:outputStylesheet`, so links to my css look like:

```
/project/javax.faces.resource/style.css.xhtml?ln=css
```

When I deploy project on tomcat on my server everything works fine. I can see my css file when I put url in broswer:

```
http://myserver.com:8080/project/javax.faces.resource/style.css.xhtml?ln=css
```

Of course I can also access it using direct url to resource like:

```
http://myserver.com:8080/project/resources/css/style.css
```

The problem starts when I configure apache to forward requests coming on port 80 to tomcat. I tried two approches:

- ajp with mod_jk
- ajp with mod_proxy

Both configurations generate invalid css file when accessing it as a jsf resource. When I put:

```
http://myserver.com/project/javax.faces.resource/style.css.xhtml?ln=css
```

I get following error message:

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

However, the direct url to my css file still works:

```
http://myserver.com/project/resources/css/style.css
```

My question is: what I missed in ajp configuration?

---

**here is configuration:**

ajp workers:

```
worker.list=ajp13_worker
worker.ajp13_worker.port=8009
worker.ajp13_worker.host=localhost
worker.ajp13_worker.type=ajp13
```

ajp connection using JK:

```
JkMount /project/ ajp13_worker
JkMount /project ajp13_worker
JkMount /project/* ajp13_worker
```

alternative ajp connection using proxy:

```
ProxyPass /project/ ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/project/
ProxyPassReverse /project/ http://127.0.0.1:80/project/
```

tomcat server.xml

```
<Connector port="8009"  enableLookups="false" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

I use:

- Tomcat 7
- Java 8
- Primefaces 4.0

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905946/jsf-url-rewriting-solution-needed contain relevant info?

Comment: I've seen it already. It doesn't - it's about changing generated urls for resources, but  urls for my project are fine, just the data is filled inproperly when the connection is done via ajp.

Comment: This error is typical for an unparseable XML document in client side. Apparently the proxy has set a XML related content type header and therefore the client (webbrowser) got confused and attempts to parse it as XML. The content type for CSS files must be `text/css`.

Comment: @BalusC thanks a lot, that give me a good hint where to look for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, as BalusC mentioned, that apache set content type to `application/xhtml+xml` and it should be `text/css`. The xml type was set because mod_mime module in apache is on. The easiest solution that works is to remove mapping between file extension and content type for xhtml. This can by done by adding:

```
RemoveType xhtml
```

line in apache config.

More solutions can be found here: https://serverfault.com/questions/544723/how-to-set-different-mod-mime-rules-for-reverse-proxy